# TKinter selecting first radio button sets all others to selected and greyed out

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a set of radio buttons, but for some reason, selecting the first one in the list sets all the others to being selected but also greyed out.  This only happens when selecting the first one, selecting any other radio button does not have this effect on the others.

[image: starting state]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
self.sort_val = None
SORT_METHODS = [('hot', 0), ('top', 1), ('new', 2), ('rising', 3), ('gilded', 4), ('controversial', 5)]
i=2
for SORT, SORTVAL in SORT_METHODS:
    self.sort = Radiobutton(frame, text=SORT, variable=self.sort_val, value=SORTVAL, tristatevalue=0)
    self.sort.grid(row=i, column=0)
    i+=1
```

Very strange behaviour, can anyone explain it?

Comment: Try using a variable for your variable instead of None, for instance: `self.sort_val = IntVar()`

Comment: Jonathan: That just causes it to be initialized with the top radio button already selected, and the problem persists.

Comment: I see. The problem seems to be your tristatevalue argument. Remove that and it works. What were you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: If you want to initialize without one of the radiobuttons preselected, then initialize the variable with a value that does not match any of the buttons. -1 for instance: `sort_val = IntVar(None, -1)`.

Comment: Jonathan: The tristate value was put in to fix a first problem: all radio buttons were initialized being selected and greyed out.  I found it via googling and it seemed to fix it.  However, building off of your suggestion, I found that using a `StringVar()` instead of an `IntVar()` actually solved the problem.  I also changed it to take strings as values

Comment: Since your values are integers, you want an IntVar. Using that and NOT using tristatevalue fixes the problem.

Comment: BTW, since you are building a reddit app, you may want to know that reddit has r/praw, r/python, and r/learnpython that can help you with this too.

Comment: Jonathan: I mentioned in a quick edit after that it has been changed to take strings instead of integers.  Also, removing the tristate value still causes all buttons to initalize as selected and greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that you must use a tkinter variable with the radiobuttons, not a standard variable. Since you are using integers, you should use an `IntVar`. You should initialize it to whatever you want for a default value.

For example:

```
self.sort_val = IntVar(value=0)
```

The second problem is related to your use of `tristatevalue`. According to the documentation for the `tristatevalue` option:

> Specifies the value that causes the radiobutton to display the multi-value selection, also known as the tri-state mode. Defaults to “”.

Because the first value is zero, when you select or deselect it, it affects all of the other radiobuttons.

If you set `tristatevalue` to `None` (or simply don't set it at all), the first radiobutton will behave just like all the others.

Comment: If I remove `tristate`, all radio buttons initialize selected and greyed out.  Same as if I set it to `None`

Comment: @1saac: my apologies. I didn't notice the other bug in your code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now.  I decided to use strings anyway (why enumerate when I don't have to) and noticed that if I just initialize `self.sort_val = 'hot'`, I still get the weird behaviour, but initializing `self.sort_val = StringVal(value='hot')` actually works... What is the difference here?

EDIT: Oh now I see, `StringVal` and `IntVal` are actually classes from tkinter

Comment: When you do `self.sort_val = hot`, you aren't setting the `StringVar` to "hot", you are destroying the `StringVar` and replacing it with a literal string.  `StringVar` and `IntVar` are objects. If you need to set their values after creating them you need to use the `set` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `tristatevalue` to a number that corresponds to the radiobuttons, they will all be selected when that specific one is selected.
If you set the `tristatevalue` high enough so that it is above all of the values of the other radiobuttons, none of them will be affected and it will act normally.
This also stops them all from being selected at the start.